# Selenium Grid server

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

what is the ideal server requirement for running parallel tests we have 100+ automation tests to run.
Currently my server is intel quad core 1.8GHz with 32 GB memory. and i am running hub and one node (with 10 maxInstances of firefox browsers) on that server. 
We plan to purchase another server. So is it better to have mediocre multiple servers or just one high end servers with several VMs running as nodes?

Answer (score 1):

Technically it does not really matter. Both solutions will work.

Scaling horizontally (more servers) should be cheaper overall and more fault-tolerant than scaling vertically (one big server). Also adding new capacity would be easier since you already integrated multiple nodes.